# Very large list of options for BuddyPress profile fields

Tags: custom-field, search, buddypress, user-interface

I’m making a site with BuddyPress xprofile fields which can have up to 40000 options. I already loaded the options into the db via csv file. Now the site loads very slowly and is basically unusable. Without the many field options, it loads fast. Once loaded, everything works fine, including the profile search. How can I prevent Buddypress from loading all options for a field by default?

I’m using select2 multiselect fields, which can load small chunks of data via AJAX/PHP. That works fine. But the slowing down occurs before initializing the select2 fields. BuddyPress is probably loading all available options by default.

WP, BP are at the newest versions. The problem persists with the twentynineteen theme (so it's not a theme problem). Currently, I'm using the free evolve theme.

I’m grateful for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I did this and it worked:
Add 3 options and go to your database. Search for any of those options, when you find them, go to the table it is in. You won't be able to see the options but just the field name. Export the table you found the options in, in CSV format. When you download the exported file, add your options to it and fill up the other columns in the same way that the other columns were filled for the other 3 options. Then import your file in the same place you exported the same file and voila, you're done :)